# Correct way to define and initialize a variable-length account in Anchor

Tags: anchor, pda, account-data

I have been following the Tic-Tac-Toe tutorial and i am experimenting with creating a PDA account in my program that holds a variable-length list of values (in particular, public keys representing mission's companion)

so my code looks something like this for one-companion case and **i want to modify it and support the case of having a variable number of companions** (e.g. 5 for a mission and 3 for another mission)

```
#[account]
pub struct MissionInfo {
    creator: PubKey,
    difficulty: u8,
    companion: Option<Pubkey>,
}

impl MissionInfo {
    const MAX_SIZE: usize = 32 + 1 + (1 + 32) 
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeMissionInfoAccounts<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
       init, 
       payer = payer, 
       space = 8 + MissionInfo::MAXIMUM_SIZE,
       seeds = [b"mission", payer.key().as_ref()], bump
     )]
    pub mission_info: Account<'info, MissionInfo>,
    ...
}
```

**What is the intended way to define and initialize the account in the case of a variable number of companions?**

I am trying something like, but i am quite a newbie so really not sure

```
#[account]
pub struct MissionInfo {
    creator: PubKey,
    difficulty: u8,
    companion: &[Pubkey], // ??
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeMissionInfoAccounts<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
       init, 
       payer = payer, 
       space = 8 + 32 + 8 + comp.size()*32, // ??
       seeds = [b"mission", payer.key().as_ref()], bump
     )]
    pub mission_info: Account<'info, MissionInfo>,
    ...
}
```

Any help and pointer is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be the first imo, but looks like you have miss typed the names.// - MissionInfo::MAXIMUM_SIZE, would be MissionInfo::MAX_SIZE
Also i would put the account discriminator together, and more important than that save the bump :D

```
#[account]
pub struct MissionInfo {
    creator: PubKey,
    difficulty: u8,
    companion: Option<Pubkey>,
    bump: u8
}

impl MissionInfo {
    pub const MAX_SIZE: usize = 8 + 32 + 1 + (1 + 32) + 1 //added bump and acc discriminator here
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeMissionInfoAccounts<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
       init, 
       payer = payer, 
       space = MissionInfo::MAX_SIZE,
       seeds = [b"mission", payer.key().as_ref()], 
       bump
     )]
    pub mission_info: Account<'info, MissionInfo>,
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

```
#[account]
pub struct MissionInfo {
    creator: PubKey,
    difficulty: u8,
    companion: Vec<Pubkey>,
    bump: u8
}

impl MissionInfo {
    pub const MAX_SIZE: usize = 8 + 32 + 1 + (8 * 32) + 1 // Max 8 Companions 
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeMissionInfoAccounts<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
       init, 
       payer = payer, 
       space = MissionInfo::MAX_SIZE,
       seeds = [b"mission", payer.key().as_ref()], 
       bump
     )]
    pub mission_info: Account<'info, MissionInfo>,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips about the bump!

I think i did not write the question clearly: i am trying to move from the version above with an Optional companion, to the version below with a variable number of companions not known beforehand (for example 5 for a mission, but 3 for another)

How would you approach that?

Comment: Ah ok now i understood. Depends if you need to deal with reasonable number of accounts if that's the case my approach would be leveraging Address Lookup Tables.
But if was a really low number of addresses probably would go companion: Vec<Pubkey> and the size would be 32 * The nr of companions. Since its a vec allows to dynamically shrink or increase the size of the memory allocated needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointers! I think is exactly what i was looking for! Generally i think the vec version should be perfect for me (im considering a max amount of 6-8 companions)

If at any point you feel like editing the main answer i will upvote and accept it! Thanks again